# How can I select all children of an element except the last child?

Tags: css-selectors, css

How would I select all but the last child using CSS3 selectors?

For example, to get only the last child would be `div:nth-last-child(1)`.

Answer (score 1033, accepted):

You can use the [negation pseudo-class `:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) against the [`:last-child` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo). Being introduced CSS Selectors Level 3, it doesn't work in IE8 or below:

```css
:not(:last-child) { /* styles */ }
```

Comment: this is used as-is? Without anything before the first colon?

Comment: you would append this to your normal base selector (`div` in the OP example)

Comment: For those using SASS, you could use `&:not(:last-child) { /* styles * }` inside of the element you want to affect.

Comment: This can be controlled from the parent as well with `> *:not(:last-child)`

Comment: This didn't work for me. The style isn't showing up! :(

Comment: I wanted every Nth except the last and found this funky syntax works: `tr:nth-child(2n):not(:last-child) { ... }`

Answer (score 135):

### Make it simple:

You can apply your style to all the div and re-initialize the last one with **:last-child**:

for example in **CSS**:

```css
.yourclass{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.yourclass:last-child{
    border: 0;
}
```

or in **SCSS**:

```css
.yourclass{
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    &:last-child{
        border: 0;
    }
}
```

- **easy to read/remember**
- **fast to execute**
- **browser compatible** (IE9+ since it's still CSS3)

---

**Edit**: I wrote this at a time `:not` was not covered by all browsers. Today I would be more balanced and would use this solution in some situations, for instance if you want to override a default behaviour.

Comment: For me at least, this has a bad code smell. You are knowingly applying a css rule to an element that you don't want it to, only to then try to cake another layer to undo it. To me, that's a bad code smell. I fear that kind of css coding can lead to harder and harder to maintain css. In other words, you're building spaghetti code css.

Comment: this could also work but the problem is when you have many css style like (border, color, font-size etc.) you will need to initialize the css style again to the :last-child. So the suitable solution is using :not(:last-child)

Answer (score 51):

Nick Craver's solution works but you can also use this:

```css
:nth-last-child(n+2) { /* Your code here */ }
```

Chris Coyier of CSS Tricks made a nice [:nth tester](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/) for this.

Comment: Mozilla has a good definition of [:nth-last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)

Comment: Some people say that `:not` pseudo is very expensive. So it might be a good idea to try to avoid it where possible.

Comment: @Neurotransmitter - references? I'm interested to know how "some people" have come to that conclusion.

Comment: @JohnChurchill if you think about it, it's quite clear: `:not` traverses the whole cascade in order to determine if it applies or not (pun intended), so it is expensive by design. You can easily avoid it in any case you can think of.

Answer (score 21):

There is a `:not` selector in css3. Use `:not()` with `:last-child` inside to select all children except last one. For example, to select all `li` in `ol` except last `li`, use following code.

```css
ol li:not(:last-child) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    foo
  </li>
  <li>
    foo
  </li>
  <li>
    foo
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: short and correct answer.

Answer (score 20):

When IE9 comes, it will be easier. A lot of the time though, you can switch the problem to one requiring :first-child and style the opposite side of the element (IE7+).

Answer (score 10):

Using nick craver's solution with [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) allows for a cross browser solution (IE6+)

Answer (score 9):

If you're using it within the nesting of the parent then the easiest way is:

```
&:not(:last-child){
  ....
}
```

**Example:**

```
.row {  //parent
 ...
 ...
 ...
 &:not(:last-child){
  ....
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

to find elements from last, use

```
<style>
ul li:not(:last-child){ color:#a94442}  
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a more generic selector, you can achieve this as seen below

```
& > *:not(:last-child) {/* styles here */}
```

Example

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>Child one</div>
  <div>Child two</div>
</div>
```

This will capture all the child DIV in the parent

Answer (score 2):

Nick Craver's solution gave me what I needed but to make it explicit for those using CSS-in-JS:

```
const styles = {
  yourClass: {
    /* Styles for all elements with this class */
    '&:not(:last-child)': {
      /* Styles for all EXCEPT the last element with this class */
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.nav-menu li:not(:last-child){
    // write some style here
}
```

this code should apply the style to all

except the last child