# Excluding last-child

Tags: css

**ul li:last-child** selects the last element of a list.

**ul li:not(...)** selects an element that is not something

What is the CSS selector for excluding the last child of an element? [I tried ul li:not(last-child)](http://jsfiddle.net/VX8TR/8/) but it didn't work.

Comment: Catch: http://jsfiddle.net/VX8TR/9/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573544/how-can-i-select-all-children-of-an-element-except-the-last-child

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Did you try:

```
ul li:not(:last-child)
```