# Is it possible to combine the css3 pseudo classes :after and :lastchild?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have a list of links and I am using the following code to put a word after each link item:

```
a:after {content: "eg"}
```

However, I don't want the content to come after the last item in the list, so ideally I would like to say something like

```
a:last-child:after {content: ""}
```

but this is stripping the content that comes after all the links. Is there anyway way of combining these two? If there is and you can explain what is going on exactly I would really appreciate it :)

Thanks

Comment: `:after` is a CSS2 pseudo-element, not a CSS3 pseudo-class. We will need to see your HTML in order to figure out the right selector to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Check this out</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Check this out</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Check this out</a></li>
</ul>
```

​
CSS:

```
a:after {content: "what what"}
li:last-child > a:after {content: ""}​
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gx9z4/1/) to demonstrate.

Also, keep in mind, if you have many users that use IE7 and IE8, the `:after` pseudo class does not work in IE7 and below, and the `:last-child` pseudo class does not work in IE8 and below. See here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd do that with a combination of `:not`, `:last-child` and `:after`. With `:not(:last-child)` you select every link except the last one:
http://jsfiddle.net/2CS9G/

```
a:not(:last-child):after{
    content: "--";
}
```

If your `a`-tags are in a list (`ul`):
http://jsfiddle.net/2CS9G/2/

```
li:not(:last-child) a:after{
    content: "--";
}
```

Comment: No support for IE < 9. No need to do this. Although it's a fantastic selector.

Comment: @Maroshii: What does this have to do with browser support? (Side note, if the OP is already using `:last-child` he's probably not interested in browser support.)

Comment: I did't know about "not"! Thanks, should make for a bit less code in the future.

Comment: @BoltClock: you are right. I thought that `last-child` had support in IE 8 but it doesn't.
However, given the case, I would always recommend to use selectors that support older browsers (which perform exactly the same task as the ones that don't).
That's why I pointed it out.

Answer (score 1):

The following selector combination worked for me:

```
#myObj ul li:last-child::after { . . . }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me > [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jkNPT/15/)

It might be that you forgot to add `display: block` to the `a`.

Comment: Inline elements can have generated content.

Comment: I am using display block but I must be overwriting something somewhere. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Does this comment by "Delphi" help? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917325/960592

> Using nick craver's solution with selectivizr allows for a cross
>   browser solution (IE6+)