# Add space between <li> elements

Tags: css

I have a nav-menu on which it seems that I can't add a space (`margin: 3px;`) between the `<li>` elements.

You can see the HTML and CSS code on this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpmKW/) or below.

You will see that I've added a `border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;` to the `#access li` to simulate the space between elements, but that is not going to work because under the nav-menu I will have a bunch of different colors. If I add `margin-button: 2px` it doesn't work.

This is the HTML:

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
        <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-41">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/fullstream/?page_id=5">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/fullstream/?page_id=7">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/fullstream/?page_id=9">Environmental Surface Cleaning</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/fullstream/?page_id=11">Regulations</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-32">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/fullstream/?page_id=13">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#access {
    background: #0f84e8; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 6px 55px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
#access ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0;
}
#access li {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 11px;
}
#access a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #eee;
    display: block;
    line-height: 3.333em;
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a,
#access a:focus {
    background: #efefef;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access a:focus {
    background: #f9f9f9; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#f9f9f9), to(#e5e5e5)); /* Older webkit syntax */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f9f9f9, #e5e5e5);
    color: #373737;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: should that be margin-bottom: 2px not margin-button: 2px? Just making sure it's not just a simple spelling error?

Comment: a bunch of different colors - wat do u mean?

Comment: I'm guessing he's going to have content under his drop down that he wants to show through the gaps?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

**UPDATE 2021**

My original answer was from 2012 when many of the Level 3 CSS Selectors did not exist. To achieve this we would need JS or other explicit CSS styles/classes to achieve it. As @AlphaX has pointed out the best solution now is simply

```
li.menu-item:not(:last-child) { 
   margin-bottom: 3px;  
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

add:

```
margin: 0 0 3px 0;
```

to your `#access li` and move

```
background: #0f84e8; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
```

to the `#access a` and take out the `border-bottom`. Then it will work

**Here:** http://jsfiddle.net/bpmKW/4/

Comment: To have it really *between* elements and so not below the last item, you can use  `li:not(:last-child)`. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573544/how-can-i-select-all-children-of-an-element-except-the-last-child

Comment: Not really a perfect solution as it adds space to the last one as well - see my answer below for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @AlphaX you are correct now. In 2012, none of those Level 3 selectors were available so you could only remove the final elements margin using JS or other CSS styles explicitly. Will update my answer for 2021

Answer (score 30):

You can use the `margin` property:

```
li.menu-item {
   margin:0 0 10px 0;   
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UAXyd/

Comment: This will add space between and below the last item, so not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 26):

There is a powerful feature of `flex` that allows for specifying space between every child without having to reference the "last-child" through `gap`. I find myself using more often than `margin` at this point:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

### Example

```css
li {
  background: red;
}

ul {
  background: silver;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I prefer using `display: grid` because by default a grid goes vertically so you only need `display` and `gap`. Also `gap` in flex-box is slightly less well supported than in grid - probably only going to be an issue with people before iOS14.5 which (just checked...) can still be a few percent of users.

Comment: Both `flex` and `grid` have their use cases. To me, this use case feels more appropriate for `flex` as this can support an unbounded amount of items in the list. `grid` shines more where you have either a known amount of items or a specific 2 dimensional layout.

Answer (score 15):

Since you are asking for **`space between`** , I would add an override to the last item to get rid of the extra margin there:

```css
li {
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

li:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

ul {
  background: silver;
  padding: 1px;  
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

The result of it might not be visual at all times, because of [margin-collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) and stuff... in the example snippets I've included, I've added a small `1px padding` to the `ul`-element to prevent the collapsing. Try removing the `li:last-child`-rule, and you'll see that the last item now extends the size of the `ul`-element.

Answer (score 6):

**Most answers** here are **not correct** as they would add bottom space to the last `<li>` as well, so they are not adding space ONLY in between `<li>` !

The **most accurate and efficient solution** is the following:

```
li.menu-item:not(:last-child) { 
   margin-bottom: 3px;  
}
```

*Explanation:*
by using `:not(:last-child)` the style will be applie to all items (li.menu-item) but the last one.

Answer (score 3):

Simple and fast. Just put css into ul element (the 'gap' property defines space between li elements):

```
display: flex;
align-items: flex-start;
flex-direction: column;
gap: 40px;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the grid layout and its gap property. You save an extra line of CSS with grid compared to flex.

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

Run the code snippet below and try it out!

```css
/* base */

ul {
  background: gray;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
}

li {
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}


/* UL Gap Adjustment */

ul {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#access a {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #eee;
    display: block;
    line-height: 3.333em;
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I see that you had used line-height but you gave it to `<a>` tag instead of `<ul>`
Try this:

`#access ul {line-height:3.333em;}`
You wouldn't need to play with margins then.

Answer (score -2):

I just want to say guys:

> Only Play With Margin

It is a lot easier to add space between `<li>` if you play with margin.