# Issue on CSS 3 Selecting All But Not the Last

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am trying to add style to all classes inside a class but not the last one by using

```
.box > .row:not(last) {   margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

but it is not working! can you please help me to fix this .Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 Selectors To Find All But Last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573544/css3-selectors-to-find-all-but-last)

Comment: Actually it's not possible to exclude the last class, but the last child or type of an element.

Comment: Please post your markup as well. Also providing an online example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `:not()` you should use valid CSS selectors. In this case you need the `:last-child` pseudo-selector.

```
.box > .row:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8m72m53r/)

Comment: Since we are not aware of the OP's markup, this answer may or [may not](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/8m72m53r/1/) work.

Comment: You're right, I just noticed your comment on the question itself and realized my mistake in interpreting his question. If the list in my fiddle has some `.row` items and then some without `.row`, this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try an easier way to do that
this will select **all childs of *.box* except the last one**:

```
.box>:not(:last-child) {
     /*styles*/
}
```

but if you're going to select only one kind of childs except last one (no matter what kind is the last child)
you should try this:

```
.box>.row:not(:last-child) {
     /*styles*/
}
```

**EDIT:** 
i hope it help's

```
.box>.row:not(:last-of-type) {
     /*styles*/
}
```