# CSS select children after filtering with condition

Tags: html, css

Some of children in my HTML have the `hidden` attribute which makes them disappear from display (by application of CSS such as `*[hidden] { display: none; }`).

However sometimes other CSS does not play well with this, because it does not ignore these hidden items. For example, suppose I want to add margins between items stacked vertically by applying `margin-bottom` to all but the last item. One may have something like this (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573544/css3-selectors-to-find-all-but-last)):

```
:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: 5px; }
```

Unfortunately this will misbehave when the last child is hidden, as the style will be applied to the hidden last child instead of the last non-hidden child.

Is it possible to make selectors such as this one work by working with the set of all non-hidden children instead of all children?

Note, this question is about the general problem of applying CSS pseudo-classes such as `last-child` on a subset of the children, the padding problem is just an example that can be solved in other ways, please avoid discussion about that specific problem.

Comment: Have you tried ':not([hidden]) { margin-bottom: 5px; }' ?

Comment: can you provide your html and css if possible?

Comment: I think the question is clear enough and doesn't need additional code. I'm asking if there is a way to select the last of a restricted subset of children, not the last child (which is what :last-child is defined to do).