# CSS not:last-child or last-child not selecting as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573544/how-can-i-select-all-children-of-an.-element-except-the-last-child) I am trying to target the highlighted div (or rather all its siblings except it).

[image]

```
div.card-body > div.form-group:not(last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I have tried various CSS but cannot figure this out. Basically I want to remove the margin from all the form-groups except the last one.

Notice that it is NOT the last div child of "card-body". I am trying to target the last div that has the class 'form-group' NOT the last div.

See this code (https://jsfiddle.net/j0gzs8ky/1/) thanks to @RyanWheale

CSS

```
div.card-body > .form-group:not(:last-child) {
  background-color: #fcc;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="form-group">
  ONE
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  TWO
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  THREE - target me
  </div>
  <div>
    I am the last div
  </div>
</div>
```

This is changing the background of THREE but I don't want that. So I am trying to target THREE only - and since there can be a different number of divs both before and after THREE, I cannot use nth child either.

So how to target the last child div that has the class "form-group"

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**

Since this is a duplicate question, and what I am trying to do is impossible, here is the workaround.

As answers can no longer be added hopefully adding this here will help others who might face this problem:

I added an extra div to contain the form-groups, and then I can target the last-child:

HTML

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="form-groups-container"
    <div class="form-group">
    ONE
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    TWO
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    THREE - target me
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    I am the last div
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.form-groups-container > .form-group:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: why you repeated the same quesiton within few minutes?

Comment: it seems my browser froze and so it double-posted when I clicked submit again

Comment: so now I cannot delete this because it has answers and neither can I delete the other copy because it is linked to this duplicate. Catch-22.

Comment: Voting to re-open so the other question can be deleted.

Comment: you need to edit your question to add the HTML before voting to reopen

Comment: I have, on the duplicate (the original)

Comment: ok so since this one has the answers then probably best to delete the other one, right? so I've added the code to both

Comment: as you like, in all the cases you cannot do what you want. It's not possible with CSS (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

Comment: @rmcsharry I flagged the other question for deletion and added proper dupe link to this.

Comment: @LGSon Thanks, much appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a colon

`:last-child`

```
div.card-body > div.form-group:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: which is a valid close reason

Comment: except that does not work, the : was a copy and paste error

Answer (score -1):

You were missing colon for the selector last-child

```css
div.form-group:not(:last-child) {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="form-group">First</div>
  <div class="form-group">2</div>
  <div class="form-group">3</div>
  <div class="form-group">4</div>
  <div class="form-group">5</div>
  <div class="form-group">6</div>
  <div class="form-group">7</div>
  <div class="form-group">8</div>
  <div class="form-group">9</div>
  <div class="form-group">Last</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, my apologies it was a copy and paste error. Question updated to illustrate the exact problem I am trying to solve.