# How to exclude css on from last element of li

Tags: css

I have the following css operating on my navbar elements

```
.nav-link:after {
content: "|";
font-weight:700;
color:#5E7B65;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

running on the following html:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaa <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">bbb</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ccc</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">ddd</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do i make it so it does not effect the last element

Comment: Please, provide full html chunk to let people see how elements go in DOM. @Castle gave exactly accurate answer based on info you provided. How he can get that every your `.nav-link` is the only child of `li`?

Comment: added to question. thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select all children of an element except the last child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573544/how-can-i-select-all-children-of-an-element-except-the-last-child)

Comment: not really because i'm not using nav-item but nav-link and in each nav-item there is only one nav-link. if i try to use the css on nav-link then the pipelines appear out ot context at the bottom and not aligned

Comment: this can be solution `.nav-item:not(:last-child) .nav-link:after`

Comment: yes. for my bootstrap html formation Banzay solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the selector :not(:last-child) that applies the css to all elements except 
   the last one

```
   .nav-link:not(:last-child):after {
    content: "|";
    font-weight:700;
    color:#5E7B65;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: this makes the pipes disappear altogether

Comment: Yes, you have to add the common css to your .nav-link and then use the not(:last-child) to exclude some style to the last element

Answer (score 0):

.nav-link:not(:last-child):after

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: Code can be formatted in several ways. For inline snippets wrap in single backticks, for multi-line indent with four spaces, or precede with a line with three backticks(and an optional language name for syntax highlighting) and follow with a line with three backticks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```css
.nav-item:not(:last-child) .nav-link::after {
  content: "|";
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #5E7B65;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaa <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">bbb</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ccc</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">ddd</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Because you need the last parent item of `.nav-link`, since your `nav-item` elements are wrapped in a container, you can use the `:not` pseudo selector to select all of the `.nav-item` elements except for the last one, and then style the child `nav-link` element.