# How do we not apply border for the last element in a container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply border for all the aside articles except the last one. Here is my code:

```html
<aside class="aside-container">
  <div>
    <h2 class="aside-header">Recommended articles</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="aside-article">
    <!--https://in.pinterest.com/pin/435934438902596641/-->
    <img src="images/Resort.jpg" alt="Picture of a pool side view in a resort" height="200" width="200" />
    <h3>
      <a href="https://www.thrillophilia.com/luxury-resorts-in-coorg">Famous resorts to stay in Coorg</a>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="aside-article">
    <!--https://in.pinterest.com/pin/AXklVB0pJT_-hAH3OJd413VeUs8U6W_ovrbYWPiertoMr4VtOrekRPE/-->
    <img src="images/TeaEstate.jpg" alt="Picture of a tea plantation with a text" height="200" width="200" />
    <h3>
      <a href="https://www.holidify.com/hotel-collections/tea-estates-in-coorg">Must visit tea estates in Coorg</a>
    </h3>
  </div>
</aside>
```

I have tried the following CSS methods:

1. ```
   .aside-container .aside-article:nth-child(1){
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   }
   ```
2. ```
   .aside-container .aside-article:nth-of-type(1){
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   }
   ```
3. ```
   .aside-container .aside-article:first-child{
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   }
   ```

It works only when I give:

1. ```
   .aside-container .aside-article:nth-child(2){
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   }
   ```
2. ```
   .aside-container .aside-article:nth-of-type(2){
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
   }
   ```

But it should work only for 1 instead of 2 right? Can someone please explain the logic behind this?

Comment: Post the CSS you currently have too please

Comment: Why not use `last-child` and remove the borders?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select all children of an element except the last child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573544/how-can-i-select-all-children-of-an-element-except-the-last-child)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `:not()` and `:last-child` to style all `.aside-article`s except the last one.

```css
.aside-article:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside-container">
  <div>
    <h2 class="aside-header">Recommended articles</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="aside-article">
    <!--https://in.pinterest.com/pin/435934438902596641/-->
    <img src="images/Resort.jpg" alt="Picture of a pool side view in a resort" height="200" width="200" />
    <h3>
      <a href="https://www.thrillophilia.com/luxury-resorts-in-coorg">Famous resorts to stay in Coorg</a
        >
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="aside-article">
      <!--https://in.pinterest.com/pin/AXklVB0pJT_-hAH3OJd413VeUs8U6W_ovrbYWPiertoMr4VtOrekRPE/-->
      <img
        src="images/TeaEstate.jpg"
        alt="Picture of a tea plantation with a text"
        height="200"
        width="200"
      />
      <h3>
        <a
          href="https://www.holidify.com/hotel-collections/tea-estates-in-coorg"
          >Must visit tea estates in Coorg</a
        >
      </h3>
    </div>
  </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your layout with one exception: first `<div>` is replaced by `<header>` which doesn't affect anything. `:last-of-type` or `:last-child` is what you need, the former being a safer choice.

```
aside .aside-article {
  border-bottom: 3px ridge tomato;
}

aside .aside-article:last-of-type {
  border: 0;
}
```

Read further for details.

```css
aside .aside-article {
  border-bottom: 3px ridge tomato;
}

aside .aside-article:last-of-type {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<aside class="aside-container">
  <header>
    <h2 class="aside-header">Recommended articles</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="aside-article">
    <!--https://in.pinterest.com/pin/435934438902596641/-->
    <img src="images/Resort.jpg" alt="Picture of a pool side view in a resort" height="200" width="200" />
    <h3>
      <a href="https://www.thrillophilia.com/luxury-resorts-in-coorg">Famous resorts to stay in Coorg</a
            >
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="aside-article">
          <!--https://in.pinterest.com/pin/AXklVB0pJT_-hAH3OJd413VeUs8U6W_ovrbYWPiertoMr4VtOrekRPE/-->
          <img
            src="images/TeaEstate.jpg"
            alt="Picture of a tea plantation with a text"
            height="200"
            width="200"
          />
          <h3>
            <a
              href="https://www.holidify.com/hotel-collections/tea-estates-in-coorg"
              >Must visit tea estates in Coorg</a
            >
          </h3>
        </div>
      </aside>
```

The layout resembles a navbar. The example below is a [semantic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#semantics_in_html) layout.

- The semantic elements are a [`<nav>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) which replaces [`<aside>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside) and a [`<header>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) which replaces a `<div>`. I used to think `<aside>` was a sidebar but it actually can be a sidebar or in the flow of content as well. It should have content indirectly related to the main content. Arguably a group of links to other related articles could be considered `<aside>` content, but the `<nav>` is more appropriate for links that take the user somewhere.
- The non-semantic HTML is semantic as a whole since they logically provide the structure and functionality of a navbar: `<ul>`, `<li>`, and `<a>`. Using `<h2>` and `<h3>` on non-[palpable content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#palpable_content) is questionable but it does look more organized.
- Each `<img>` and `<h3>` is wrapped in a `<a>` since users (including myself if I trust a site) click images if they look like they are associated with the text of a link.
- No classes are assigned only [type selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) are used to clearly illustrate the use of the [`:nth-of-type` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

  ```
  nav li:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  ```

  That applies to all `<li>` that are the last of it's sibling `<li>` and are descendants of a `<nav>`.

If you still prefer to use `<aside>`, replace the first `<div>` with `<header>` and the rest of the `<div>` with something less generic like `<article>`. In the CSS replace `nav` with `aside` and `li` with `article`, then remove `ul` and replace it with:

```
aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The most imporatant thing I hope you get out of this is to avoid using `<div>` (and `<span>`) as much as possible because if you expand your HTML in the future, it can become a mass of unreadable markup bloated with divs having multiple hyphenated classes.

*Note: Other than the style applied to the `<li>` directly, it is suggested styles since the unmentioned CSS and HTML isn't included.*

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

nav li {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border-bottom: 3px ridge tomato;
}

nav li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

nav li a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <header>
    <h2>Nav Header</h2>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="https:/example.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
        <h3>First LI Title</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https:/example.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
        <h3>LI Title 2</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https:/example.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
        <h3>LI Title 3</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https:/example.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
        <h3>LI Title 4</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https:/example.com">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
        <h3>Last LI Title</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```